# What letter spacing for visually impaired?

Tags: accessibility, readability, font

What letter spacing is best to read for visually impaired people? Should the letters be close together or should they have more space in between?

I am asking because APHont, a font made for visually impaired, has a quite narrow letter spacing by default.

**Narrow**

[image: Narrow letter spacing]

**Wide**

[image: Wide letter spacing]

Answer (score 3):

Spacing helps people with dyslexia, it helps me too, the narrow kerning is tough to read.

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/06/120607105712.htm